# How to remove opened folders from MacOS dock VSCODE

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, dock

Is it possible to remove some folders i opened in Vscode so that it doesn't show inside dock

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72318), right-clicking or long-pressing on the VSCode application icon in your dock on macOS brings up a context menu that does not match the recently opened items.

To resolve this, go to `File > Open Recent > Clear Recently Opened` to remove all items from the dock. You can remove individual items with `File > Open Recent > More...`, which will open the VSCode Command Palette, and allow you to click 'x' to remove individual files.